Can I use an SVG image as texture for an object
I have an SVG image I wish to use as a texture in a material, instead of importing it as an object itself. Is it possible to do so, without installing any addons? It just never imports correctly as a grease pencil object. I'm open to scripting, if necessary.

why not convert it to a png file?

@HarryMcKenzie PNG is not a very good format. It's slow, compression is not that great...

or another file format since svg is not possible :)

No, unfortunately that is not possible. You can see in the documentation that supported image formats do not include vector images in SVG format.
If you want to use an SVG image as a texture you will need to convert it into a bitmap image format like for example EXR, webp, targa or other. See this amazing answer to help you chose a format:
What image format encodes the fastest, or at least faster? PNG is too slow.
It's possible to do that with Python scripting, but it will just be the same as converting the SVG image to a bitmap format in any external software which might be easier and more convenient.

Nice answer! But, why can't it be used as a texture in an object's material? Or can it, and it's just not implemented?

I don't know. I am not a developer so I can only guess the technical reasons. Since it's vectors, it is quite different than bitmap images so probably a whole different way of sampling would be needed for rendering and also different algorithms for displaying it on objects in the viewport. I have no idea how this would work, because I don't have much knowledge nor understanding in this area, so I guess my comment doesn't mean much and take it as meant for entertainment purposes, I guess. :D I know it cannot be used and it's not implemented though.

Well, thinking about it, we sort of have "vector" textures. They are procedural textures. They work... I don't know. It would be interesting to know more about this. I haven't heard much about that during my 17 or so years of learning and working with 3d though so either I am not as sharp as I would like to believe, or it's not a very popular topic :D .
